# Summing in multi-level relationship

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Using EF code first, I have the following 4 entities

```cs
public class Item {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Location {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class InventoryAdjustment {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<AdjustmentLine> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class AdjustmentLine {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to get the sum of all inventory adjustments for each item at each location using minimal database round-trips.

The best I achieved so far is:

```cs
using (var db = new InventoryContext()) {
  var items = db.Items.ToList();
  var locations = db.Locations.ToList();

  foreach (var item in items) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name+":");
    foreach (var location in locations) {
      Console.Write("\t" + location.Name + ": ");
      var qty = db.InventoryAdjustments
          .Where(p => p.Location.Id == location.Id)
          .SelectMany(p => p.Lines)
          .Where(p => p.Item.Id == item.Id)
          .Select(p => (int?)p.Quantity)
          .Sum();
      Console.WriteLine(qty ?? 0);
    }
  }  
  Console.Read();
}
```

The above outputs:

```
Item1:
    Location1: 2
    Location2: 12
    Location3: 21
Item2:
    Location1: 4
    Location2: 0
    Location3: 0
Item3:
    Location1: 1
    Location2: 17
    Location3: 0
```

But with 3 items and 3 locations in the database, the above code causes 11 calls to the database. 2 for getting items and locations, and 9 for calculating the sum of quantity.

Is there a better way to get the sum with the least amount of round-trips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably work:

```
using (var db = new InventoryContext())
{
    var items = db.Items.ToList();
    var locations = db.Locations.ToList();

    items
        .Select(item =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + ":");
            return item;
        })
        .SelectMany(item => locations.Select(location => new { item, location }))
        .GroupJoin(
            db.InventoryAdjustments
                .SelectMany(
                    inventoryAdjustment => inventoryAdjustment.Lines.Select(
                        adjustmentLine => new { key = new { locationId = inventoryAdjustment.Location.Id, itemId = adjustmentLine.Item.Id }, adjustmentLine.Quantity }
                    )
                ),
            x => new { locationId = x.location.Id, itemId = x.item.Id },
            y => y.key,
            (x, y) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t {0}: {1}", x.location.Name, y.Sum(a => a.Quantity));
                return 0;
            }
        ).ToList();
    Console.Write("\nPress any key...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I get an error: 'lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree'